# How to integrate Python function into a MyBB registration page

Tags: python, mybb

I have some Python code that I would like to integrate into a webpage. I have absolutely no idea how to do this. It can't be done by pasting into HTML like PHP. What is the easiest way it could be done? I have heard of things like Django but my efforts in getting that to work have been futile.

Here are some of the things I need to be able to do:

- Read the input from an HTML input box
- Process the input
- Search a text file

Here is an example of the Python code I'm running on my computer that I want to transfer to the web:

This is the code that will perform a binary search on a text file

```
with io.open('final.txt', encoding='latin-1') as myfile:
    data = myfile.readlines()
    low = 0
    high = (len(data)-1)
    while (low <= high) and not Found:

        mid = int((low+high)/2)

        if data[mid].rstrip() == Password:
            Found = True
            break
        elif Password < str(data[mid]):
            high = mid - 1
        elif Password > str(data[mid]):
            low = mid + 1
```

Basically, the idea is this: I have been developing an app that will assess a password's strength. I have written the app in Python. What I want to do now is integrate it into a MyBB registration page so that it can do this assessment on someone's inputted password during the registration process.

Can someone please point in the right direction with concise, clean instructions to do this?

Comment: What makes you think this is possible?

Comment: "It has always been possible to use Python for creating web sites" , "Since most servers support Python, it is easy to use Python to create dynamic web sites." - Python documentation

Comment: This is best done through AJAX calls; reading server files from the client side is impossible in PHP too (it only preprocesses what the webserver returns)

If you're willing to part with Python, you could have a JSON file of these retrieved, and use javascript to determine whether the password is in the file (which also prevents passwords being sent in cleartext(!!)) EDIT: would this count as an answer?

Comment: I don't want to read server files from the client side though. What I want to do is take what someone inputs in the "password" field during registration, send it to the server and process it server side.

Comment: Ah okay; thought you misunderstood inline PHP in such a manner. That said though, sending passwords in cleartext any more than necessary is highly inadvisable, and client-side validation would successfully obviate this (and would provide a speedier user experience than an AJAX call, which is the only other option other than maybe wiring the Python into the PHP somehow and having it validate after submission, which would not only be a less user-friendly experience, but would be immensely difficult to implement, I think)

Comment: I don't know whether PHP and/or MyBB can make command line calls, but if so, your easiest option might be to turn your python code into a command line program.